# Title is not set for Users and Tags pages for mobile web

Tags: bug, mobile-web, window-title

[Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) and [User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) pages have no set title for mobile web.
You can see it by inspecting HTML code or more easily more opening in the desktop browser and looking into tab's title. It would contains page URL instead of title. E.g. in Firefox:

> [image: path]